# Intermitent 404 response from Google Recaptcha API

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, recaptcha

Hello since yesterday we are experiencing intermitent 404 responses from google recaptcha api. The strange thing is that we havent modified the code.

Sometimes recaptcha box loads sucessfully, but sometimes it throws a 404 an error like the script wasnt loaded correctly

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZa0r.png)

What I noted is that when it loads correctly, the google script url is like this:

```
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/wzdvOBEvXKKaOu7ghdslx1-G/recaptcha__pt_br.js
```

But when it fails, it is loaded like this:

```
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases//recaptcha__pt_br.js
```

Our code to include google api:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=aminvisiblecaptchaOnloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            var aminvisiblecaptchaOnloadCallback = function() {
                recaptcha = grecaptcha.render('amasty_recaptcha', {
                    'sitekey': '<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('aminvisiblecaptcha/general/checkbox_key'); ?>',
                    'theme': '<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('aminvisiblecaptcha/backend/badge_theme'); ?>',
                    'size': '<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('aminvisiblecaptcha/backend/size'); ?>'
                });
            };
        </script>
```

Did anyone came accross something like this before?

thanks in advance.

Comment: _"But when it fails, it is loaded like this"_ - that appears to be exactly the same URL you have shown for both cases.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It does not load the hashed version. It loads like this: https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases//recaptcha__pt_br.js